# Factory Girl is looking for factories.rb in the wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

I'm trying to get Factory Girl working, but I keep getting this error when I run my tests:

```
/Users/dm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require': no such file to load -- .//Users/dm/Projects/volunteers/spec/factories.rb (LoadError)
```

The problem is obviously the ./ in front of the path. But I can't figure out how it's getting there. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: post the code, where you "require" factories.rb and where is it exactly in the app structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug in factory_girl that was fixed in 2.0.1. I just forced the correct version in my gemfile and all was good.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/153